# C++ Array that repeats every pair of numbers in the sequence

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

I cant seem to figure out how to repeat the numbers stored in an array. For example, if the user inputs (1,2,3,4), the out put would be (1,1,2,3,3,4,4).

Here is what I have so far that only gets the numbers to be stored in the array.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arr[4];
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
        cin>>arr[i];

        cout<<arr[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: So... you want to print out each number twice? (I also dont see why youre storing them in an array if youre printing them out right away).

Comment: `cout<<arr[i] << " " << arr[i];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{ 
    const int size_of_input = 4;
    const int twice_size_of_input = 2*size_of_input;
    int arr[twice_size_of_input ];
    for (int i=0; i<twice_size_of_input ; i++) 
    {
        cin>>arr[i];
        arr[i+1]=arr[i];
        i++;
    }
    for (int i=0; i<twice_size_of_input ; i++) 
    {
        cout<<arr[i];    
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Assuming that you want the array with repeated nos.

Comment: Just use constants there? Why would you use defines. What is this? C?

Comment: My bad. Fixed it. Thanks! And yes, I thought it was C.